# user-based modeling with elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, web-applications

I would like to add elasticsearch to my existing webapp, currently based on mysql. 
To simplify, my application is a kind of blog container: every user writes some posts and those posts can be public or private. 
Once a user subscribes to another, his timeline is filled with its and his friend's posts. Posts can be commented or rated. Comments can be rated as well.

Now, I need to index such timelines in elasticsearch, because I want to provide a good search engine, based on posts and comments content, posts and comments rating and user's data, but I have some troubles figuring out how to best model my elasticsearch index.

Clearly, the relationship between "timeline" and "post" is a many-to-many, since every user's timeline might contain several posts, according to the social graph.

Reading the elasticsearch documentation, I've found some different solution, but I'm not sure of anyone of them.

1. Denormalization.
   My first attempt has been to denormalize data this way: Create a "post" type in the ES index and link it with a parent-child relationship with the "timeline". 
   This way I have no duplicated posts, but I have a "timeline" object for each user-user relationship. Moreover, as a rdbms user, I thought I would have got only one timeline object per user, but unfortunately, this is not true: elasticsearch creates a single timeline object for each post, with the same id value but different routing (but probably this is my fault because I'm pretty new to ES).
2. User-based data
   Another approach would be the user-based data, i.e. creating a (fake) index for each user. But again, according to the docs, I see that the relationship between user and timeline is a one-to-many (ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/shared-index.html)
   Am I missing something?

So, just to recap: My application has users, posts, comments and ratings. User's timeline are made of subscribed users posts. Since posts can be private - i.e. only subscribed users can read them, I would like to perform searches "timeline" based. To do that, I would like to model my data to elasticsearch.

What would be the best way to model it?